How can I use http protocols for an app running on Windows from another app running on WSL Ubuntu?
my question may be very basic, I am deploying to a flask app, using the wsgi gunicorn and sockets, it is running WSL ubuntu 20.04. 6 LTS, inside it I make a POST to another application which I have it running in powershell (windows11), during testing I have noticed that the app in windows can make post to the wsl app, but not the other way around, I have tried to perform the processes mentioned in forums.
I have created rules in firewall to be able to post.
I have added the port and ip to the proxy.
I have disabled the firewall, it works but it is not secure.
I have changed the version of wls from 2 to 1, however, when I run my app I get an error that makes it stop.I get an error saying that the protocol is not compatible, so I have to go back to version 2.
Not working with tcp only with IPV4.
What other solutions do you recommend? I can't find a solution.
Thank you for your support.

Your post is about as incoherent as it can be.  Are both of these apps running on the same PC?

Yes both applications are in the same PC, only one (the one that receives the POST) I run it in windows terminal for some library issues and the other one I run it in WSL Ubuntu for the reason that gunicorn can be run only in unix environments.

That information should have been in the question, you're lucky I knew what WSL meant.  Unfortunately I don't know enough about the bridge between the two OS to help.

Are you able to ping between the two?  That would be a necessary first step.

Thank you very much, I will edit the question.
Sure, I can ping between the two and I get a reply.
